# Getting 5-tuple information in a php script

Tags: php

Is there any simple way to get the 5-tuple information (source ip, source pprt, destination ip, destination port, layer-4 protocol) in php?

I see that there is $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] that gives me source ip. How can I get remaining 4 elements?

EDIT: From http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php, I see that there are $_SERVER elements for REMOTE_ADDR, REMOTE_PORT, SERVER_PORT, SERVER_ADDR that the webserver I am using is not setting. I can modify the webserver code to export these elements as well.

Would it be safe to assume that layer-4 protocol would always be tcp?

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER)` and look. That's what you have to work with.

Comment: Following link has some information: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: yes thats what I did. But the particular web server that I am using is not setting those variables. Thanks though.

Comment: Because it seems, that you are using a "not so common" server/server-setting, you should describe it a little bit.

Comment: I am using mini_httpd. I will have to modify the source to set those elements correctly. thank you for the answer.

Comment: [It's written](http://www.acme.com/software/mini_httpd/) that `mini_httpd` is supporting CGI. If that's really true, you must look for environment variables, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface#Environment_variables_passed_to_a_CGI_program and http://www.w3.org/CGI/ and http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php . Try `var_dump($_ENV);` and additionally make use of the [`getenv` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) to access environment variables.

Comment: I had grepped through mini_httpd's source code. And except, REMOTE_ADDR, none of the other variables are defined. So I think I will have to modify the code. But the wikipedia CGI link was really useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

4 of 5. "layer-4 protocol" is usually always TCP

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
```

http://php.net/reserved.variables.server

Comment: If you don't use a very exotic configuration, its always TCP. Webservers uses TCP and PHP usually runs under a webserver.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, depending on your network configuration, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` may give you the IP of your load balancer/proxy/firewall. In this case, you may need to use `$_SERVER['X-FORWARDED-FOR']`.

Comment: thanks. that is a useful tip because I think I will add some load balancer in the front.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

`var_dump($_SERVER);`

```
foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value){
    echo "$key: $value<br />";
}
```

src: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=516172

```
function get_real_ip()
{
     $ip = false;
     if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
     {
          $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
     }
     if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
     {
          $ips = explode(", ", $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
          if($ip)
          {
               array_unshift($ips, $ip);
               $ip = false;
          }
          for($i = 0; $i < count($ips); $i++)
          {
               if(!preg_match("/^(10|172\.16|192\.168)\./i", $ips[$i]))
               {
                    if(version_compare(phpversion(), "5.0.0", ">="))
                    {
                         if(ip2long($ips[$i]) != false)
                         {
                              $ip = $ips[$i];
                              break;
                         }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         if(ip2long($ips[$i]) != - 1)
                         {
                              $ip = $ips[$i];
                              break;
                         }
                    }
               }
          }
     }
     return ($ip ? $ip : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other ones are:

- REMOTE_PORT
- SERVER_ADDR
- SERVER_PORT

I dont know any variable that stores IPv4 information.